# Why FileNotFoundError on Path.rename while using Pyfakefs?

Tags: python, pathlib, pyfakefs

I wrote a test for a function that renames files from e.g. `/videos/vid_youtube.mp4` to `/videos/youtube/vid.mp4`. The test patches the fs with Pyfakefs.

When the code actually renames the file, I get this error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/code/project/test/DLV/videos/vid_youtube.mp4' -> '/home/user/code/project/test/DLV/videos/youtube/vid.mp4'
```

This is how I set up fakefs

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    self.setUpPyfakefs()
    self.fs.create_dir(Path(Dirs.VIDEOS))  # /home/user/code/project/test/DLV/videos
    self.fs.create_file(Path(Dirs.VIDEOS / "vid_youtube.mp4"))
```

The code under test.

```
class Files:
    @staticmethod
    def rename_video_files():
        all_files = Collect.video_files()

        for files_for_type in all_files:
            for file in all_files[files_for_type]:
                path = Path(file)
                platform = Files.detect_platform(path)
                platform_dir = Path(Dirs.VIDEOS, platform)
                platform_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

                new_name = path.stem.replace(f'_{platform}', '')
                new_path = Dirs.VIDEOS / platform / f'{new_name}{path.suffix}'

                old_path = Dirs.VIDEOS / path
                old_path.rename(new_path)   # throws FileNotFoundError
```

I debugged the test and the method under test and even passed the fake fs to rename_video_files(fakefs) to inspect the files and directories. All files and directories look correct.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely the static initialization of `Dirs.VIDEOS`. This is initialized at load time as a `pathlib.Path`, and won't be patched later at the time you setup `pyfakefs` (the same problem would happen if you where to use `unittest.patch` for patching).

There are two ways to fix this:

- adapt the code to not initialize the path statically
  This could be done by statically defining the `str` path, and converting it to a `Path` at run time, or by using a method to get the path instead of an attribute (e.g. `Dirs.VIDEO()` instead of Dirs.VIDEO`).
- adapt the test to reload the tested code
  If reloading the tested code after `pyfakefs` has been initialized, it will be correctly patched. `pyfakefs` provides an [argument](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/usage.html#modules-to-reload) in `setUpPyfakefs` that does that:

```py
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import TestCase

from my_module import video_files
from my_module.video_files import Dirs, Files


class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.setUpPyfakefs(modules_to_reload=[video_files])
        self.fs.create_dir(
            Path(Dirs.VIDEOS))  # /home/user/code/project/test/DLV/videos
        self.fs.create_file(Path(Dirs.VIDEOS / "vid_youtube.mp4"))
```

(under the assumption, that your code under test is located in `my_module.video_files.py`)

*Disclaimer*:
I'm a contributor to pyfakefs.

Comment: Indeed Dirs.VIDEOS etc. were fields instantiated as Path objects. After refactoring them to strings and turning them at paths during runtime, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: turning them *to paths